# Just got a winter bash notification

Tags: bug, winter-bash

Bizarrely when clicking the "back" button just now on StackOverflow I saw a light blue notification and on clicking it was told I had received a Carl Fredricksen Hat on the English Language and Usage site (certainly I was navigating back to a page loaded today - I don't have any still loaded from when the winterbash itself was active).

Looks like a temporary glitch but thought I'd report it in case other people experience the same issue.

Comment: Maybe the ruling AI noticed the current blizzards in the US and deduced it's still winter.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? What browser/OS are you using (and their versions)?

Comment: @cybermonkey - No I don't have a screenshot, I navigated away and can't reproduce it. Chrome 47.0.2526.111 on Windows 10.

Comment: Caching. Has to be caching ;)

Comment: @ChrisF My thoughts too. I don't see anything obviously winter bash related when looking at the page source on SO. Maybe a single server has the old code or it was served from cache somewhere.

Comment: Well, technically it's still winter @Jongware

Comment: @ChrisF not enough cache invalidation ...

Comment: @ChrisF If is is caching then it's obviously not being handled correctly on the system.

Comment: @ChrisF http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ (link may be invalid due to caching)

Comment: Argh... hats. Hats. HATS!

Comment: Never blame caching, blame the developer who forgot to clear it

Comment: @Jongware Technically? By the calendar, it's winter until March 19!

Comment: @Kaz According to my view out of my window, it is spring.

Comment: @Kaz, according to the North East US, [it's winter all right](http://mic.com/articles/133324/blizzard-2016-how-much-snow-did-new-york-city-get-during-winter-storm-jonas#.L1Yf3Iu3r).